# Open iphone application content in safari

Tags: objective-c, ios, safari, load

I am looking for answer for following question. please help me if you know answer.

Question - I have a image stored locally in iphone application space. I want to display the image in iphone safari not on UIWebView. There is requirement like this, It sound weird but image should be displayed on safari by any ways.

Comment: Please tell us in detail what you want to do, I'm sure there is a better solution then the one you are asking for.

Answer (score 2):

Upload it to a remote server and open the URL from your app. It will launch `Safari` and display the image. There is no other way... You can't open a local path from `Safari`.

Comment: Can we open singed XML file in iPhone safari?

Comment: Not locally. Otherwise you can open a xml file on a remote url address, but it will not be displayed as raw xml, but only the values. You can try it with a sample xml..

Answer (score 0):

This line will launch Safari from an app for a given NSURL:

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[self imageFileURL]];
```

Ordinarily, you'd use a URL pointing to a local file:/// with the path of your image file.

However, it seems that isn't allowed on iOS (apps are sandboxed) so you'll need to use a remote URL, as the other responder suggests.